# How to highlight the first 2 td elements of a tr element when hovering over either of them?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am new to CSS3 and I have been trying to do this one thing for a couple of hours now and I can't seem to get it right. I can't help but think it is something really simple that I just can't see.

Here is the table that I have:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="gridtable">
    <tr>
        <th>US State:</th>
        <th>Abbreviation:</th>
        <th>US State:</th>
        <th>Abbreviation:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
        <td class="left">Alabama</td>
        <td>AL</td>
        <td class="left">Montana</td>
        <td>MT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
        <td class="left">Alaska</td>
        <td>AK</td>
        <td class="left">Nebraska</td>
        <td>NE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to style the state cell and it's abbreviation when the user hovers on either the state or the abbreviation. With my limited skill I was able to get it to work when the user hovers over the state name using the following CSS:

```
table.gridtable td.left:hover,
.left:hover + td {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

And here is the rest of the relevant CSS code styling the table:

```
table.gridtable {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.gridtable th {
    font-size: 14px;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #dedede;
}

table.gridtable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

table.gridtable td.left {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #d3eef5;
}
```

There is also another table on the page, but that one should not be styled the same way.

I hope this is enough information to explain what I mean. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have used 'table.gridtable' in your css (for background highlight css too), so if you want the same css should not be applied in the second table, then you
can add one more class to this first table and use that instead (to highlight).
So, that particular css will only be applicable to the table where you want.

Or alternatively, you can even do this for 'td'.

So, your code will become something like this -

```
<table border="0"     cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="gridtable gridtable1">

table.gridtable1 td.left:hover,
.left:hover + td {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

I hope, you are looking for something like this.

**EDIT:**

I have added one class `abbr` to the abbreviation `td` -

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="gridtable">
    <tr>
        <th>US State:</th>
        <th>Abbreviation:</th>
        <th>US State:</th>
        <th>Abbreviation:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
        <td class="left">Alabama</td>
        <td class="abbr">AL</td>
        <td class="left">Montana</td>
        <td class="abbr">MT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
        <td class="left">Alaska</td>
        <td class="abbr">AK</td>
        <td class="left">Nebraska</td>
        <td class="abbr">NE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("table.gridtable").find("td.left").hover(function(){
                  $(this).next().css("background-color", "pink"); 
                  $(this).css("background", "none"); });

      $("table.gridtable").find("td.abbr").hover(function(){
              $(this).prev().css("background-color", "pink");  
              $(this).css("background", "none");
});                                    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I only mentioned the other table, because I thought it might be relevant. I have the other table styled properly. The only thing I can't get to work is to change the color on the 1st td when hovering over the 2nd td and the change the color on the 3rd td when I hover over the 4th td in any given tr of this table. Using the same tag for the 1st and 2nd td and setting it's hover state to a different color, only changes the color for the td I hover over - not both.

Comment: So, does that mean, if you hover over the abbreviation, then the respective state should be highlighted and if you hover over the state then its respective abbreviation should be highlighted?

Comment: OK, so that can be easily achievable by jQuery. I have updated the code. Please see if that works for you.

Comment: I don't really know much about jQuery and how to work with it, so I can't really say. @LcSalazar provided a great vanilla JavaScript solution. I also caved in and split the table in 2, which resulted in pure CSS solution. I posted my solution as an answer to my question. Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to use an element to change the previous one. And although we have ways of change subsequent siblings with css, there's no such thing as a previous sibling selector.

The only solution I see is a Javascript approach. I'll give you the basic js funcionality, with pure vanilla, but of course  a framework like JQuery would make your life easier:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('.left');
for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    var td = tds[i];

    //Assign the mouse over/out events for a hover effect
    td.onmouseover = 
    td.onmouseout = 
    td.nextElementSibling.onmouseover = 
    td.nextElementSibling.onmouseout = function() {

        //Checks which one is the sibiling
        var sibling = this.matches('.left') ?
                this.nextElementSibling : this.previousElementSibling;

        //Verifies if any of them are hovered
        if(this.matches(':hover') || sibling.matches(':hover')) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = sibling.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
        }
        else {
            this.style.backgroundColor = sibling.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
    }
}
```

This would mock a hover effect, and maybe you would need to improve the style change part, perhaps assigning a class or something.

But at least it is working, regardless of which one of the td's you hover.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1kox1abo/1/

Comment: This works great! Thanks so much! ... I knew there was no "previous selector" and I am no JavaScript master (novice at best). I resorted to splitting the data in 2 tables and sticking them in <div> consisting of 2 other <div> tags and just styling the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @LcSalazar below is exactly what I was looking for.

Since I was trying to figure this out on my own and I don't really know much of JavaScript I ended up splitting the data in 2 tables, placing them next to each other and just styling the table row.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="right">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="gridtable">
    <tr>
      <th>US State:</th>
      <th>Abbreviation:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
      <td class="left">Alabama</td>
      <td>AL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
      <td class="left">Alaska</td>
      <td>AK</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="gridtable">
    <tr>
        <th>US State:</th>
        <th>Abbreviation:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
        <td class="left">Montana</td>
        <td>MT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
        <td class="left">Nebraska</td>
        <td>NE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="state">
        <td class="left">Nevada</td>
        <td>NV</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
/* CSS to Highlight each row on hover */
table.gridtable .state:hover td {
    background-color: LightSkyBlue;
}
```

Full solution (all states and CSS) on CodePen: http://codepen.io/petarmihaylov/pen/xGFqi/